# target type depending generic rule

Tags: cmake

My project contains a lot of libraries and executables. On Windows a .rc file is used to embed meta informations (version, original file name, ...). One of these meta informations is FILETYPE (VFT_DLL, VFT_APP). So I add a -D TYPE definition to the resource compiler (which I evaluate inside the .rc) to distinguish between dll/exe.
Example:

```
add_library (myLib SHARED "src/myLib.cpp"
                          "src/myLib.rc")
target_include_directories (myLib PUBLIC "include")
set_source_files_properties("src/myLib.rc" APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS "-DDLL")
```

I won't repeat myself in dozens of CMakeLists, is there a possibility to create a generic rule (e.g. in a .cmake include) that .rc files will be compiled with a target depending flag (-DDLL in case of SHARED library)?

Comment: `-DDLL in case of SHARED library` and it's without `-DDLL` when the target is not a shared library?

Comment: yes, that's what I try to achieve.

Comment: Does builting the rc file "depend" on the target it's used for? Ie. does rc file depend on the `target_include_directories`? Maybe more "cmake" way - creat two object libraries from that rc file one compiled with DLL and one without and use different rc object target depending on library.

Comment: No, the rc file currently just contains "static" informations like language id, version info etc. Not dependent from clients using this lib. But I want to add infos like used compiler/version, optimisation etc. too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a small wrapper function:

```
# Or maybe not object, depending on what you want
add_library(rc_for_shared OBJECT src/myLib.rc)
target_compile_definitions(rc_for_shared PRIVATE -DDLL)
add_library(rc_for_executable OBJECT src/myLib.rc)

# This is a draft from my memory
function(target_add_the_rc_file target)
     get_target_properties(target PROPERTIES TYPE type)
     if (type STREQUAL "SHARED")
        target_link_libraries(${target} rc_for_shared)
        # or maybe target_source(${target} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:rc_for_shared>)
        # depending on what you want
     elseif(type STREQUAL "EXECUTABLE")
        target_link_libraries(${target} rc_for_executable)
     endif()
 endfunction()
```

then you would:

```
add_library(myLib SHARED src/myLib.cpp)
target_include_directories(myLib PUBLIC)
target_add_the_rc_file(myLib)
```

Comment: Ah, I am a cmake beginner and had not noticed user defined cmake functions before. This opens up completely new possibilities ... Thanks